# Solve directed graph problem with Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, graph-theory, graph-algorithm, directed-graph

I have a seemingly simple problem to be solved in a directed graph. Given a directed graph, such as the one in the picture, I need to find the pathway between two "boundary nodes" (A and B, in the picture) that has the smallest "maximum cost". Each node in the graph has a certain "cost" to be invaded, so for each possible pathway we can find the maximum cost. For instance, in the picture PATH 3 wins since the maximum cost is smaller than the maximum cost of PATH 1 and PATH 2.

I always heard that Tensorflow is a library that allows you to solve generic graph problems, so I wonder if there is any "ready to use" library/back-end around Tensorflow that could allow me to solve this problem?

Thank you, 
Rafael.

[Example of directed graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwgsh.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Tenserflow is a machine learning framework which is not needed for the the problem you want to solve. Your problem can be solved by simple modification of [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58452795/what-is-the-algorithm-that-finds-the-minimal-highest-cost-of-all-edges?noredirect=1#comment103243869_58452795) question. The only difference is that your weights are on the nodes and not on edges, but you can simply construct a new graph where you give every original edge a weight of zero and replace every node by two new nodes, one for outgoing edges and one for incoming edges. You then also add an edge from the incoming edge node to the outgoing edge node with weight of the original node. I let you verify that a path of minimum maximal cost per edge in this new graph corresponds to a path of minimum maximal cost per node in the original graph and which you can find using the modified Dijkstra algorithm.