# Quickest Route between stations with cheapest cost | python

Tags: python

I have a list
with 3 elements station1, station2 and price

```py
my_list = [["st1" ,"st2" ,750] ,["st2" ,"st3" ,1000] ,["st4" ,"st3" ,775] ,["st2" ,"st4" ,575]]
```

How to get the quickest and cheapest path between the stations.

It we want to goto st4 or if we want to goto st2.

is there any simpler approach to this

```py
for i in my_list:
  if i[0] == start & i[1] == end:
    print("valid")
  else:
    if tempcost < i[2]:
      print(i[0] + i[1])
      tempcost = i[2]
      tempindex = count
      tempcost = i[2]
    count += 1
```

Im trying this but stucked

Comment: Keywords: Minimum Cost Possible from Weighted Graph
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/program-to-find-out-the-minimum-cost-possible-from-weighted-graph-in-python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the algorithm that finds the minimal highest cost of all edges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58452795/what-is-the-algorithm-that-finds-the-minimal-highest-cost-of-all-edges)

Comment: Your question talks about "quickest and cheapest" as if there were two separate measures of cost, but your data structure has only one number associated with each edge. Assuming that you are just being redundant, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem. If you are not simply being redundant, you have an under-specified multi-objective optimization problem. In general such problems don't have clear-cut solutions since there might be a trade-off between how "cheap" and how "quick" a path is, with no one right answer in how to deal with the trade-off.